# is_same returning false when comparing class template instantiation with its base class template?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-meta-programming, variadic-templates

***Edit: Somehow I thought the compiler was creating `B` just as `A<int, int, string>`, leading to my assumption about how is_same should evaluate them, regardless of inheritance/derivation.  My bad :(  Sorry for subsequent misunderstandings :\ ***

Making some meta-functions to check for my custom types, and ran into this issue, but not sure I understand what's going on here.  I think I can work around it by comparing this_t member of a known type to this_t of whatever parameter is passed, but I just want to understand why the 1st and 3rd is_same tests fail:

```
template<typename... Args> struct A {
    typedef A<Args...> this_t;
};

struct B : A<int, int, string> {
};

//tests
std::is_same<A<int, int, string>, B>::value; //false
std::is_same<A<int, int, string>, typename B::this_t>::value; //true
std::is_same<B, typename B::this_t>::value; //false

//more tests for kicks
std::is_base_of<A<int, int, string>, B>::value; //true
std::is_base_of<A<int, int, string>, typename B::this_t>::value; //true
std::is_base_of<B, typename B::this_t>::value; //false
```

Is is_same differentiating by way of the `A<...>` base?  What's the appreciable difference between `A<int, int, string>` and `B`?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by your edit, please expound.

Comment: I mean you're swinging at the low-hanging fruit with your answer.  If an error in the usage of `B` is encountered when compiling, I get a message back referring to `B` as `A<int, int, string>` as opposed to `B`.  So if the compiler sees `B` as `A<int, int, string>` then I'm not sure why the is_same test would fail.

Comment: Also. What output do you expect? All `true`? or all `false`? or what?

Comment: Well then, you should ask about that error.  Show the code the generates it, and show the error message.

Comment: C'mon guys.  I'm asking for help, not sponsoring a "call me an idiot" contest.  I'm trying to understand what's going on.  If the compiler refers to `B` as `A<int, int, string>`, then what gives when I pass is_same an `A<int, int, string>` and ask it to compare that to a `B`?

Comment: My compiler doesn't refer to B as A<int, int, string>.  If yours does, then show us the code in which it does that.

Comment: Downvote... really?  Someone needs a nap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The is_same is basically a template with a specialization

```
template<class T, class U>
struct is_same : false_type
{ };

template<class T>
struct is_same<T, T> : true_type
{ };
```

That will never give you true, unless you have **exactly** the same type. Note that there is only one `T` in the specialization. It can never match both A and B.

Comment: I need to clarify my question a bit, as to what assumptions I've made about the compiler.  I'm trying to get some code that will show what's happening.  Will post an edit when I do.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful answer.  I would have figured A and B to fail is_same, but I was working from an incorrect assumption about what my compiler was doing with `B`.  Somehow I had it figured that it was creating `B` in terms of `A<int, int, string>`, which it was not :(

Answer (score 3):

The `is_same` trait is true only if the two types passed to it are the exact same type. `B` is not the same type as `A<int, int, string>`.

Answer (score 2):

`is_same` tests if two types are the same type.

`B` is not the same type as `A<int, int, string>`.  How could it be?  It's derived from it.